# How to merge 2 dataframe by closest geometry and date&time in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geometry, geopandas

I have 2 different dataframe. In "weather" dataframe there are many geometry on same date and time. In "road" dataframe there ara linestrings, dates and times but here they are not the same date or same time, they all different.

The thing I want to do is merge 2 dataframe by date-time and geometry. Shortl I wanna combining 2 dataframe by closest geometries at the same date and time

I tried to do it this way

1. First I tried to find same dates and times from "weather" dataframe for the date from "road" dataframe
2. And then there are rows more than one and there are points. I tried to find closest point(it's in "weather" dataframe) to the linestring(it's in "road" dataframe)
3. Last thing I tried to do is delete the points (delete those rows) from "weather" dataframe. only the row with the closest point will remain.

I did somthing but I guess it's wrong. How can I fix this situation. Is there a other way to do this?

Here is a sample of "road" dataframe:

```
{{'roadId': {0: 10500,
  1: 10500,
  2: 10500,
  3: 105400,
  4: 105400,
  5: 106600,
  6: 14100,
  7: 22800,
  8: 22800,
  9: 22800,
  10: 29000,
  11: 31500,
  12: 32100,
  13: 36400,
  14: 36400,
  15: 36600,
  16: 40400,
  17: 40400,
  18: 420253800,
  19: 420253800,
  20: 420253800,
  21: 420253800,
  22: 420253800,
  23: 420253800,
  24: 420253800,
  25: 420253800,
  26: 420253800,
  27: 420253800,
  28: 46700,
  29: 46700,
  30: 48600,
  31: 48600,
  32: 48600,
  33: 48600,
  34: 48600,
  35: 48600,
  36: 48600,
  37: 48600,
  38: 48600,
  39: 48600,
  40: 48600,
  41: 48600,
  42: 53700,
  43: 60001200,
  44: 60002000,
  45: 60002000,
  46: 60002000,
  47: 60002100,
  48: 60002100,
  49: 60002100},
 'date': {0: '2021.03.08 02:00:00',
  1: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  2: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  3: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  4: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  5: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  6: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  7: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  8: '2021.03.08 01:45:00',
  9: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  10: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  11: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  12: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  13: '2021.03.08 00:00:00',
  14: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  15: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  16: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  17: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  18: '2021.03.07 21:15:00',
  19: '2021.03.07 20:45:00',
  20: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  21: '2021.03.07 22:30:00',
  22: '2021.03.08 00:30:00',
  23: '2021.03.08 01:45:00',
  24: '2021.03.08 01:45:00',
  25: '2021.03.08 02:00:00',
  26: '2021.03.08 02:30:00',
  27: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  28: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  29: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  30: '2021.03.07 21:30:00',
  31: '2021.03.07 22:30:00',
  32: '2021.03.08 01:00:00',
  33: '2021.03.08 00:30:00',
  34: '2021.03.08 03:45:00',
  35: '2021.03.08 02:15:00',
  36: '2021.03.08 02:00:00',
  37: '2021.03.08 02:30:00',
  38: '2021.03.08 05:15:00',
  39: '2021.03.08 05:00:00',
  40: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  41: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  42: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  43: '2021.03.07 22:30:00',
  44: '2021.03.07 23:30:00',
  45: '2021.03.08 05:45:00',
  46: '2021.03.08 04:15:00',
  47: '2021.03.07 21:15:00',
  48: '2021.03.08 02:30:00',
  49: '2021.03.08 05:45:00'},
 'lin': {0: 'LINESTRING (32.85619 39.868728, 32.856321 39.868657, 32.856477 39.868615)',
  1: 'LINESTRING (32.85619 39.868728, 32.856321 39.868657, 32.856477 39.868615)',
  2: 'LINESTRING (32.85619 39.868728, 32.856321 39.868657, 32.856477 39.868615)',
  3: 'LINESTRING (32.882227 39.550864, 32.880966 39.551685)',
  4: 'LINESTRING (32.882227 39.550864, 32.880966 39.551685)',
  5: 'LINESTRING (32.692448 39.885163, 32.692012 39.885222)',
  6: 'LINESTRING (32.86239 39.900284, 32.862381 39.900456)',
  7: 'LINESTRING (32.812381 39.878539, 32.81255 39.879431)',
  8: 'LINESTRING (32.812381 39.878539, 32.81255 39.879431)',
  9: 'LINESTRING (32.812381 39.878539, 32.81255 39.879431)',
  10: 'LINESTRING (32.712708 40.404688, 32.711973 40.404542, 32.711355 40.404252, 32.710675 40.403367, 32.71017 40.402972, 32.707958 40.402167, 32.705775 40.40114, 32.704602 40.400377, 32.703107 40.399538, 32.7023 40.399137, 32.701442 40.398798, 32.699727 40.398285, 32.698995 40.397953, 32.69837 40.39751, 32.697003 40.396632, 32.696455 40.396157, 32.69596 40.395658, 32.695558 40.395147, 32.695092 40.394375, 32.694597 40.394143, 32.693903 40.394207, 32.693316 40.394351)',
  11: 'LINESTRING (32.651653 39.850165, 32.652376 39.850618)',
  12: 'LINESTRING (32.678197 39.867385, 32.678069 39.867217)',
  13: 'LINESTRING (32.744751 39.782534, 32.744926 39.786808)',
  14: 'LINESTRING (32.744751 39.782534, 32.744926 39.786808)',
  15: 'LINESTRING (32.887934 39.952421, 32.887946 39.952489)',
  16: 'LINESTRING (32.975037 39.971029, 32.974902 39.971053)',
  17: 'LINESTRING (32.975037 39.971029, 32.974902 39.971053)',
  18: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  19: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  20: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  21: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  22: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  23: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  24: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  25: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  26: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  27: 'LINESTRING (32.95387116 39.28371696, 32.95342296 39.28059297, 32.953392 39.28009203, 32.95338084 39.27934899, 32.95344888 39.27871998, 32.95354104 39.278205, 32.95368792 39.27774699, 32.95393992 39.27714696, 32.95427184 39.27654603, 32.95456596 39.276108, 32.95491012 39.27567897, 32.95526004 39.27529296, 32.95572588 39.27484098, 32.95624212 39.27442104, 32.95674504 39.274083, 32.95744416 39.27368304, 32.95808784 39.27336903, 32.95879992 39.27308796, 32.95962108 39.27282597, 32.96107512 39.27240198, 32.96199492 39.27213099, 32.96280492 39.27187404, 32.96360808 39.27159297, 32.96435616 39.271302, 32.96566296 39.27076803)',
  28: 'LINESTRING (32.871431 39.979258, 32.871111 39.979476, 32.87096 39.979521)',
  29: 'LINESTRING (32.871431 39.979258, 32.871111 39.979476, 32.87096 39.979521)',
  30: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  31: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  32: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  33: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  34: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  35: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  36: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  37: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  38: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  39: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  40: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  41: 'LINESTRING (32.637394 39.991609, 32.637595 39.991583, 32.637753 39.991543, 32.63852 39.99122)',
  42: 'LINESTRING (32.724833 39.996181, 32.724756 39.995943)',
  43: 'LINESTRING (32.71277988 39.80887704, 32.71290084 39.80894598, 32.71340196 39.80906001, 32.71361688 39.80909799)',
  44: 'LINESTRING (32.76150192 40.014702, 32.76157284 40.01517603)',
  45: 'LINESTRING (32.76150192 40.014702, 32.76157284 40.01517603)',
  46: 'LINESTRING (32.76150192 40.014702, 32.76157284 40.01517603)',
  47: 'LINESTRING (32.707125 40.00806801, 32.70731796 40.00878099, 32.70739392 40.00901598, 32.70750588 40.00922901, 32.70763692 40.00942998, 32.7078 40.00960602, 32.70797604 40.00976901, 32.70823884 40.00998303, 32.70883896 40.010355, 32.70925188 40.010661, 32.70963708 40.01099796, 32.71014 40.01150403, 32.71041792 40.01175396, 32.71069404 40.01193801, 32.71094784 40.01206698, 32.71131396 40.01221602, 32.71158 40.012299, 32.71187592 40.01235903, 32.71401 40.012416)',
  48: 'LINESTRING (32.707125 40.00806801, 32.70731796 40.00878099, 32.70739392 40.00901598, 32.70750588 40.00922901, 32.70763692 40.00942998, 32.7078 40.00960602, 32.70797604 40.00976901, 32.70823884 40.00998303, 32.70883896 40.010355, 32.70925188 40.010661, 32.70963708 40.01099796, 32.71014 40.01150403, 32.71041792 40.01175396, 32.71069404 40.01193801, 32.71094784 40.01206698, 32.71131396 40.01221602, 32.71158 40.012299, 32.71187592 40.01235903, 32.71401 40.012416)',
  49: 'LINESTRING (32.707125 40.00806801, 32.70731796 40.00878099, 32.70739392 40.00901598, 32.70750588 40.00922901, 32.70763692 40.00942998, 32.7078 40.00960602, 32.70797604 40.00976901, 32.70823884 40.00998303, 32.70883896 40.010355, 32.70925188 40.010661, 32.70963708 40.01099796, 32.71014 40.01150403, 32.71041792 40.01175396, 32.71069404 40.01193801, 32.71094784 40.01206698, 32.71131396 40.01221602, 32.71158 40.012299, 32.71187592 40.01235903, 32.71401 40.012416)'}}
hava=pd.read_csv("C:/Users
```

Here is a sample of "weather" dataframe:

```
{'Lat': {142761: 40.13,
  142762: 40.13,
  142763: 40.13,
  142764: 40.13,
  142765: 40.13,
  142766: 40.13,
  142767: 40.13,
  142768: 40.13,
  142769: 40.13,
  142770: 40.13,
  142771: 40.13,
  142772: 40.13,
  142773: 40.13,
  142774: 40.13,
  142775: 40.13,
  142776: 40.13,
  142777: 40.13,
  142778: 40.13,
  142779: 40.13,
  142780: 40.13,
  142781: 40.13,
  142782: 40.13,
  142783: 40.13,
  143474: 39.93,
  143475: 39.93,
  143476: 39.93,
  143477: 39.93,
  143478: 39.93,
  143479: 39.93,
  143480: 39.93,
  143481: 39.93,
  143482: 39.93,
  143483: 39.93,
  143484: 39.93,
  143485: 39.93,
  143486: 39.93,
  143487: 39.93,
  143488: 39.93,
  143489: 39.93,
  143490: 39.93,
  143491: 39.93,
  143492: 39.93,
  143493: 39.93,
  143494: 39.93,
  143495: 39.93,
  143496: 39.93,
  144187: 39.95,
  144188: 39.95,
  144189: 39.95,
  144190: 39.95},
 'Lon': {142761: 33.1,
  142762: 33.1,
  142763: 33.1,
  142764: 33.1,
  142765: 33.1,
  142766: 33.1,
  142767: 33.1,
  142768: 33.1,
  142769: 33.1,
  142770: 33.1,
  142771: 33.1,
  142772: 33.1,
  142773: 33.1,
  142774: 33.1,
  142775: 33.1,
  142776: 33.1,
  142777: 33.1,
  142778: 33.1,
  142779: 33.1,
  142780: 33.1,
  142781: 33.1,
  142782: 33.1,
  142783: 33.1,
  143474: 32.86,
  143475: 32.86,
  143476: 32.86,
  143477: 32.86,
  143478: 32.86,
  143479: 32.86,
  143480: 32.86,
  143481: 32.86,
  143482: 32.86,
  143483: 32.86,
  143484: 32.86,
  143485: 32.86,
  143486: 32.86,
  143487: 32.86,
  143488: 32.86,
  143489: 32.86,
  143490: 32.86,
  143491: 32.86,
  143492: 32.86,
  143493: 32.86,
  143494: 32.86,
  143495: 32.86,
  143496: 32.86,
  144187: 32.73,
  144188: 32.73,
  144189: 32.73,
  144190: 32.73},
 'Tarih': {142761: '2021.03.08',
  142762: '2021.03.08',
  142763: '2021.03.08',
  142764: '2021.03.08',
  142765: '2021.03.08',
  142766: '2021.03.08',
  142767: '2021.03.08',
  142768: '2021.03.08',
  142769: '2021.03.08',
  142770: '2021.03.08',
  142771: '2021.03.08',
  142772: '2021.03.08',
  142773: '2021.03.08',
  142774: '2021.03.08',
  142775: '2021.03.08',
  142776: '2021.03.08',
  142777: '2021.03.08',
  142778: '2021.03.08',
  142779: '2021.03.08',
  142780: '2021.03.08',
  142781: '2021.03.08',
  142782: '2021.03.08',
  142783: '2021.03.08',
  143474: '2021.03.08',
  143475: '2021.03.08',
  143476: '2021.03.08',
  143477: '2021.03.08',
  143478: '2021.03.08',
  143479: '2021.03.08',
  143480: '2021.03.08',
  143481: '2021.03.08',
  143482: '2021.03.08',
  143483: '2021.03.08',
  143484: '2021.03.08',
  143485: '2021.03.08',
  143486: '2021.03.08',
  143487: '2021.03.08',
  143488: '2021.03.08',
  143489: '2021.03.08',
  143490: '2021.03.08',
  143491: '2021.03.08',
  143492: '2021.03.08',
  143493: '2021.03.08',
  143494: '2021.03.08',
  143495: '2021.03.08',
  143496: '2021.03.08',
  144187: '2021.03.08',
  144188: '2021.03.08',
  144189: '2021.03.08',
  144190: '2021.03.08'},
 'Saat': {142761: '00:00',
  142762: '03:00',
  142763: '06:00',
  142764: '09:00',
  142765: '12:00',
  142766: '15:00',
  142767: '18:00',
  142768: '21:00',
  142769: '00:00',
  142770: '03:00',
  142771: '06:00',
  142772: '09:00',
  142773: '12:00',
  142774: '15:00',
  142775: '18:00',
  142776: '21:00',
  142777: '00:00',
  142778: '03:00',
  142779: '06:00',
  142780: '09:00',
  142781: '12:00',
  142782: '15:00',
  142783: '18:00',
  143474: '00:00',
  143475: '03:00',
  143476: '06:00',
  143477: '09:00',
  143478: '12:00',
  143479: '15:00',
  143480: '18:00',
  143481: '21:00',
  143482: '00:00',
  143483: '03:00',
  143484: '06:00',
  143485: '09:00',
  143486: '12:00',
  143487: '15:00',
  143488: '18:00',
  143489: '21:00',
  143490: '00:00',
  143491: '03:00',
  143492: '06:00',
  143493: '09:00',
  143494: '12:00',
  143495: '15:00',
  143496: '18:00',
  144187: '00:00',
  144188: '03:00',
  144189: '06:00',
  144190: '09:00'},
 'Weather': {142761: 1,
  142762: 1,
  142763: 1,
  142764: 1,
  142765: 1,
  142766: 5,
  142767: 5,
  142768: 1,
  142769: 1,
  142770: 1,
  142771: 5,
  142772: 5,
  142773: 11,
  142774: 5,
  142775: 5,
  142776: 1,
  142777: 7,
  142778: 7,
  142779: 4,
  142780: 4,
  142781: 4,
  142782: 1,
  142783: 4,
  143474: 1,
  143475: 1,
  143476: 1,
  143477: 1,
  143478: 5,
  143479: 5,
  143480: 5,
  143481: 1,
  143482: 1,
  143483: 1,
  143484: 1,
  143485: 5,
  143486: 11,
  143487: 5,
  143488: 1,
  143489: 1,
  143490: 7,
  143491: 7,
  143492: 4,
  143493: 4,
  143494: 4,
  143495: 4,
  143496: 4,
  144187: 1,
  144188: 1,
  144189: 1,
  144190: 1},
 'geometry': {142761: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671948>,
  142762: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671b08>,
  142763: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671ac8>,
  142764: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671a88>,
  142765: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6716c8>,
  142766: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671808>,
  142767: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671788>,
  142768: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671908>,
  142769: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671248>,
  142770: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671388>,
  142771: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671c08>,
  142772: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671d48>,
  142773: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671c88>,
  142774: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671688>,
  142775: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6717c8>,
  142776: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671e88>,
  142777: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671988>,
  142778: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671e48>,
  142779: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671dc8>,
  142780: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671d08>,
  142781: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671d88>,
  142782: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671f48>,
  142783: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d671b48>,
  143474: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6943c8>,
  143475: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694548>,
  143476: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694388>,
  143477: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6942c8>,
  143478: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694688>,
  143479: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6945c8>,
  143480: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694648>,
  143481: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694108>,
  143482: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6947c8>,
  143483: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694488>,
  143484: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694788>,
  143485: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694708>,
  143486: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6948c8>,
  143487: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6946c8>,
  143488: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694888>,
  143489: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694848>,
  143490: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6949c8>,
  143491: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694808>,
  143492: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694748>,
  143493: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694b08>,
  143494: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694a48>,
  143495: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694ac8>,
  143496: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d694588>,
  144187: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6b7408>,
  144188: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6b73c8>,
  144189: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6b7548>,
  144190: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ca1d6b7388>}}
```

Here is my code:

```
liste={}
lis={}
for i in range(road.date.count()):            
    for n in range(weather.Tarih.count()):
        if (weather.index == (142600+n)).any()==True:
            if road.date[i][0:10]==weather.Tarih[142600+n]:
                if str(pd.Timestamp(road.date[i][11:16]).round('180min').to_pydatetime())[11:16]==weather.Saat[142600+n]:
                    point = weather.geometry[142600+n]
                    liste[142600+n]=point
    if len(liste)!=0:
        print(liste)
        for a, p1 in liste.items():
            line = shapely.wkt.loads(road.lin[i])
            p2 = nearest_points(line, p1)[0]
            distance = math.sqrt(((p1.x-p2.x)**2)+((p1.y-p2.y)**2))
            lis[a]=distance
        b=min(lis.values())
        b=bul(b,lis)
        lis.pop(b)
        for k in liste.keys():
            weather.drop([k], axis=0, inplace=True)
        liste.clear()
        lis.clear()
```

This code is for merge the dataframes by date and time

```
road['date'] = pd.to_datetime(road['date'])
road = road.sort_values(by = 'date')
weather['date'] = weather['Tarih'] + ' ' + weather['Saat']
weather['date'] = pd.to_datetime(weather['date'])
weather = weather.sort_values(by = 'date')
newdf = pd.merge_asof(left = road, right = weather, on = 'date', tolerance = pd.Timedelta('180min')) #in weather dataframe there is a difference of 3 hours between the hours like 0-3-6-9
```

but when I run the first code and then I run this one after a certain point it becomes nan value

Answer (score 0):

You should use `direction="nearest"` otherwise you're only looking forward

```py
newdf = pd.merge_asof(left = road, right = weather, on = 'date', tolerance = pd.Timedelta('180min'), direction="nearest")
```

Also, with this tolerance, you'll have one `nan` anyways, but you can increase it, to remove all `nan`s.